# How to replace Diffuse?

Tags: software-recommendation, 20.04

Why was Diffuse left out of Universe repository of Ubuntu 20.04? What to use instead (if you don't want to use plain `diff` but a graphical software)?

Comment: There's a fork that's been updated to use Python 3 at https://github.com/MightyCreak/diffuse

Comment: `diffuse` is the only GUI diff tool I know, that can compare an unlimited amount of file at once. all others support at most 4, usually 3, sometimes only 2 files at once.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible to install from manually downloaded packages from 18.04 LTS:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/diffuse/diffuse_0.4.8-3_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./diffuse_0.4.8-3_all.deb ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

---

Other good alternatives are [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) (`meld` package) or [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) (`kdiff3` package).

Answer (score 6):

As of summer 2020, the updated fork of diffuse at https://github.com/MightyCreak/diffuse is the best way to go. It is very usable directly from source on Ubuntu 20.04. The main prerequisites are python3 and python3-gi, both of which are new enough on Ubuntu 20.04. Install python3 and python3-gi with

```
sudo apt install python3-gi
```

On non-desktop machines, you may need to install also the following packages that are otherwise typically installed already:

```
sudo apt install gobject-introspection gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gnome-icon-theme python3-gi-cairo
```

Then clone the diffuse fork from github to a folder of your liking. To run diffuse, it's sufficient to call the python script `src/usr/bin/diffuse`. It may be even more convenient to add the bin-folder to your PATH:

```
export PATH="${HOME}/your/path/to/diffuse/src/usr/bin:${PATH}"
```

The path setting can also be placed in your shells startup scripts (i.e. `.bashrc` or similar) to have diffuse always available.

Comment: The project now uses `meson` as a build system, the instructions on https://github.com/MightyCreak/diffuse are up to date.

Comment: The app from this project is also available as a Flatpak package: [Diffuse—Linux Apps on Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.github.mightycreak.Diffuse).

Answer (score 5):

The package was dropped from Debian back in 2019, thence from Ubuntu also.

- Looks like it was abandoned upstream. Their mailing list has no responses from the developers for several years.